# Git commit and checkout

Tags: git, commit, vcs-checkout

When I make changes to my local branch, and commit them, what do others have to do to see those changes in their local repositories? What does 'git checkout' do?

Comment: You may want to read up more on git basics https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control

Comment: Read this:
http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/

Comment: As pointed out in your other question, please review the git documentation. You seem to be missing foundational concepts of git.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I recommend you to check the official [Git's *Getting Started* Guide](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control) in order to learn further how Git works.

Answering your question, you first need to understand that all changes you make on your local computer won't be seen to others unless you **push** your code to a remote repository (where others could **pull** these changes to their local machines from).

The `git checkout` command will let you switch from branches.
There's more info and practical examples on the [git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout).